# Loops and float numbers

Tags: python

I’m taking an online basic programming class and I’m completely lost on this assignment. Our book went over basic loops, but not how to find max, min, or average in a loop with values input by a user. Here is my assignment:

Write a loop control program that will provide important statistics for the grades in a class. The program will utilize a loop to read five floating-point grades from user input. Ask the user to enter the values, then print the following data: Average Maximum Minimum

My textbook and instructor have really given me no guidance on how to use floating numbers in a loop. Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
for grade in range(5):
    int(input("Enter Grade (percentage): "))
    if max:
        print('Max:')
    if min:
        print('Min:')
else:
    print('Average:')
```

This allows me to get the loop to run 5 times but how do I actually calculate the min, max, and average for unknown variables?

Answer (score 0):

I don't do python, but I'd know how to approach this problem.

For the average, declare a variable called sum or something and set it to 0. Then, every time you get an input, add that value to the sum. After 5 inputs, print that sum divided by 5. That'll be the average.

To get the max, initiate a variable to 0. On input, check if that input is greater than the currently stored maximum. If so, set the variable to that input. After 5 inputs that variable will contain the max.

Similarly for the min. But make sure to set that variable to something big at the start (like 100000), and then check if the new input is smaller than that variable.

Also, if you're supposed to use floats, don't cast your user input to an int. Use float instead.

Answer (score 0):

You use floating numbers in a loop the same way you use them outside the loop.
The loop does not change anything.

But, it seems you are misunderstanding the task wording:
You are not suppose to print the min, max, and average calculation **inside** the loop.

That would be impossible, since you can not know them, until the user inputs all 5 grades.

What you are suppose to do inside the loop, are 4 steps:

1. Read a `float` from the user. Currently, you are trying to read an `int` for some reason. Do you know how to read a `float` in Python?
2. Add it to the sum you will use **after** the loop to calculate average.
3. See if it is the max of all numbers the user inputted so far.
4. See if it is the min of all the numbers the user inputted so far.

Once you exit the loop, all you have to do is print 3 numbers:
The max and min you found and the average calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make a list first, 
Then create a for loop that will run 5 times, range(5) should work. 
Then exit the loop and run an average, min and max

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please improve your answer by adding some code, and clarifying what it adds to the existing answers.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a simple function for this task. You can do the following:

```
def take_what(statistic = None):
    f = []
    for grade in range(5):
        f.append(int(input("Enter Grade (percentage): ")))

    if statistic == "max":
        print('Max: {}'.format(max(f)))
    elif statistic == "min":
        print('Min: {}'.format(min(f)))
    else:
        print('Average: {}'.format(sum(f)/len(f)))

print(take_what('max'))
print(take_what('min'))
print(take_what())
```